# oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350) . Exception while update

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am updating records using JDBC `PreparedStatement`, and I'm not understanding where I went wrong. I think exception is occurring on `excuteUpdate()` or is there anything wrong in my code?

My code for updating looks like below code

```
try {
         cn.setAutoCommit(false);
         ps=cn.prepareStatement("update ISEVAENQUIRY set DATED=?,SOURCE1 =?,SOURCE2=?,CALLON=?,CALLBY =?,NAMEN=?,SBIC=?,SBISMSSENTDATE=?"
                + ",NUMBER1=?,FORMFILLEDUPC =?,FORMFILLEDUPDATE=?,NUMBER2=?,FORMCOURIREDC=?,FORMCOURIREDDATE=?,EMAIL1 =?,FORMRECIC=?,FORMRECIDATE=?,EMAIL2 =?"
                + ",PAYEMNTRCC=?,PAYDATE=?,PAN=?,REMARKS=? where NUMBER1=?");
        ps.setString(1,val[0] );
        ps.setString(2,val[1] );
        ps.setString(3,val[2] );
        ps.setString(4,val[3] );
        ps.setString(5,val[4] );
        ps.setString(6,val[5] );
        ps.setString(7,val[6] );
        ps.setString(8,val[7] );
        ps.setString(9,val[8] );    
        ps.setString(10,val[9] );
        ps.setString(11,val[10] );
        ps.setString(12,val[11] );
        ps.setString(13,val[12] );
        ps.setString(14,val[13] );
        ps.setString(15,val[14] );
        ps.setString(16,val[15] );
        ps.setString(17,val[16] );
        ps.setString(18,val[17] );
        ps.setString(19,val[18] ); 
        ps.setString(20,val[19] );
        ps.setString(21,val[20] );
        ps.setString(22,val[21] );
        ps.setString(23,val[8] );   
        int c=ps.executeUpdate();
         cn.commit();  
        if(c !=0)
        {
            result="updated";
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when `executeUpdate()` following exceptions are coming

```
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:283)
 oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
 oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
 com.iseva.Servlet.UpdateIsevaEnquery.doGet(UpdateIsevaEnquery.java:65)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't understand why this happens, can any one help me?

Comment: Make sure you have connected to oracle successfully (Adding logs to getting the connection object, etc). From the stacktrace, there is a network connection error between your desktop and the Oracle Server.

Comment: thank you @ LFF 27 . i debugged my code oracle Connection is fine.

Comment: What is the whole exception?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, specify the full version of your Oracle database and the full version of your Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: i just added exception stackTrace will you please check it

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel i have edited with exception printStack

Comment: no, you haven't added the full stacktrace: The exception at the beginning is missing. Please add it as well